# css custom in gridview with asp.net/bootstrap

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, gridview

Good night, I'm doing a simple post system with GRIDVIEW using ASP.NET / BOOTSTRAP, as gridview is a simple table I'm using templatefild and itemtemplate with table td and tr to be "LOOKING" with a BLOG! Until then everything ok, I managed to leave it in the order I want (title, date, abstract, link to see the whole post, author), but I wanted to apply CSS to these items of course, I wanted to leave something like this:
[HOW I WANT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xtxrq.png)

Applying the bootstrap classes I can get this:
[WITH THE BOOTSTRAP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORuSn.png)

As you can see anything close to what I want, then I decided to make my own CSS, but nothing catches it, I create a class with my name, I'll print it in css, I apply the COLOR property for example and the font does not change color, the bootstrap classes work, mine do not! Remembering that I'm using WEBFORM + MASTER PAGE, then on my master page there's a fluid container, a row, and a column and inside that has the contentplaceholder! I have a gridview with colums, templatefild, item template, table, tr and td! I APPLY css in GRIDVIEW, but it does not handle! follows examples:

Master's code:

```html
      <!-- CONTEUDO -->
    <div class="container-fluid bg-page">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8">

                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="conteudo" runat="server">
                </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

            </div>
```

Page code that is called within the contentplaceholder:

```html
     <div class="container-fluid bg-page" id="conteudo">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <asp:GridView ID="gdv_posts" runat="server"  ShowHeader="false" CssClass="table table-striped" GridLines="None" AutoGenerateColumns="false" PageSize="5" OnRowCommand="gdv_posts_RowCommand" AllowPaging="True" OnPageIndexChanging="gdv_posts_PageIndexChanging">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <table >
                                <tr >
                                    <td>
                                        <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "titulo")%>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "data")%>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "descrição")%>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:Button ID="btn_visualizar" runat="server" Text="Visualizar" class="btn btn-link nav-link" CommandName="Visualizar" CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "id")%>' />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "autor")%>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>

                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
```

CSS code:

```css
.postagens{
    color: aqua!important;

}

.postagens table{
    color: aqua !important;
}

.postagens td{
    color: aqua !important;
}

.postagens tr{
    color:aqua !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a GridView with Bootstrap because it creates its own non-RWD table HTML. Look to using a [ListView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398790.aspx) instead. There are tutorials out there on how to do it with a GridView but it's overkill and unnecessary since the ListView allows you to use your own responsive Bootstrap table markup in its template.

Comment: Unfortunately I did not learn to work with LISTVIEW, I saw some tutorials but I did not understand very well, I have been trying since you answered, how would a code with listview with pagination, and in the example style? please.

Comment: If you read the documentation in the link, you will see that the ListView has its own DataPager control. It even gives a code sample:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datapager?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2